# Here/Nokia Map markers not always shown

Tags: maps, markers, here-api

I have a few map markers that are located all over the place and I want to auto zoom to show them all.

The code I have should work fine but sometimes (seems to depend whereabouts the map markers are) it doesn't always zoom correctly to show the markers.

Here's a fiddle (with example markers to show the problem): http://jsfiddle.net/amnesia7/9YUVe/embedded/result/ using the following marker locations:

```
// Add markers to the map for each location
addMarker(1, "Hello 1", [-18,178.333]);
addMarker(2, "Hello 2", [-18.5,180]);
addMarker(3, "Hello 3", [-18.5,-178.333]);
```

The auto-zoom has gone completely wrong and seems to be zoomed in on the sea somewhere.

Looks to be a bug to me because it seems to depend on whereabouts the map markers are as to whether it zoom correctly or not.

---

**UPDATE**

I've created, what I hope will be, a simpler version using the HERE developer demo for "Zoom to a set of markers"

http://jsfiddle.net/amnesia7/uhZVz/

You need to zoom the map out to see the markers that should be in view by default.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a bug to me  too, and only occurs when markers cluster around the 180th line of longitude.
Seems that  the **zoomTo()** calculation is incorrect in this case, only taking in to account the last marker since it is on the "wrong" side of the international date line.

Anyway, **getWidth()** on the viewport does seem to work, so you *could* hack in your own **zoomTo()** function as shown in the kludge below.

Also note the use of **kml=auto&map=js-p2d-dom** when loading the library - this uses the DOM implementation rather than the canvas implementation this properly shows markers on both sides of the 180th line of longitude.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML SYSTEM>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7; IE=EmulateIE9" />

        <style type="text/css">

            html {
                overflow:hidden;
            }

            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                overflow: hidden;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                position: absolute;
            }

            #mapContainer {
                width:100%;
                height: 100%;
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
                position: absolute;
            }

 </style>
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="http://api.maps.nokia.com/2.2.3/jsl.js?kml=auto&map=js-p2d-dom"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mapContainer"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
 /*    Set authentication token and appid
*    WARNING: this is a demo-only key
*    please register on http://api.developer.nokia.com/
*    and obtain your own developer's API key
*/
nokia.Settings.set("appId", "APP_ID");
nokia.Settings.set("authenticationToken", "TOKEN");


// Get the DOM node to which we will append the map
var mapContainer = document.getElementById("mapContainer");
// Create a map inside the map container DOM node
var map = new nokia.maps.map.Display(mapContainer, {
    // initial center and zoom level of the map
    center: [52.51, 13.4],
    zoomLevel: 13,
    components: [
        // We add the behavior component to allow panning / zooming of the map
        new nokia.maps.map.component.Behavior()
    ]
});


// We create an instance of Container to store markers per city
var myContainer = new nokia.maps.map.Container();

/* We add all of the city containers to map's object collection so that
 * when we add markers to them they will be rendered onto the map
 */
map.objects.add(myContainer);

// We create several of marker for a variety of famous landmarks
var firstMarker = new nokia.maps.map.StandardMarker(
        [-18, 178.333],
        { text: 1 }
    ),
    secondMarker = new nokia.maps.map.StandardMarker(
        [-18.5, 180],
        { text: 2 }
    ),
    thirdMarker = new nokia.maps.map.StandardMarker(
        [-18.5, -178.333],
        { text: 3 }
    );

// Add the newly created landmakers per city to its container
myContainer.objects.addAll([firstMarker, secondMarker, thirdMarker]);

/* Now we calculate the bounding boxes for every container.
 * A bounding box represents a rectangular area in the geographic coordinate system.
 */
var myBoundingBox = myContainer.getBoundingBox();


zoom = 1;
map.setCenter(myBoundingBox.getCenter());
map.setZoomLevel(zoom);


while (map.getViewBounds().getWidth() >  myBoundingBox.getWidth())   {
    zoom++;
    map.setZoomLevel(zoom); 
}
zoom--
map.setZoomLevel(zoom--);

</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Jason, I'll give that a try, although using dom rather than canvas will adversely affect mobile use so I could do with it sorting out, as I'm sure Nokia would. Do you know where to report a bug because on http://developer.here.net/faqs it says "I think I have discovered a bug. How do I report it?" but doesn't actually have a link to a discussion board to post a bug report.

Comment: Hi Jason Fox, your suggestion did work but I don't really want to accept your answer until I know the issue (the canvas not showing markers correctly when moving the map left and right and the incorrect zoomTo feature) is added to a bug report somewhere.

Comment: @user1116573 The original bug (JSLA-3074) was raised internally many months ago. What is missing at the moment is a mechanism for exposing these bug reports to the public. I've raised a **second** internal bug (DEVPRES-10) specifically to try and address this gap.

Comment: Jason Fox, I've accepted your answer but I'm surprised it takes so long for bugs to be ironed out. Is there somewhere I can subscribe to be notified of new API version releases so that I can keep my app up-to-date as bugs get fixed (eg a blog) without having to remember to keep checking back at the developer website?

Comment: Jason Fox, it also needs `if (zoom > 17) { break; }` in the `while loop` before `zoom++;` to stop it trying to zoom in too much which causes it to break. (I've just chosen `17` myself, I think you can actually zoom in a bit further than that without it breaking.

Comment: This bug has finally been fixed in the Enterprise 2.5.0 release. The fix will also be included in equivalent Public 2.5.0 release when it goes live.

Comment: Thanks Jason Fox, that's great to hear. Since we're only upto 2.2.4, I assume it's gonna be a while before 2.5.0 makes it out into the wide world, but looking forward to it.